# Plotting solution DSolve

Tags: plotting, differential-equations

I am trying to plot a solution of a  differential equation system. This is what I have:

```
eqn = {x''[t] + w^2*x[t] == 0, y[t] == x'[t]}; w = 1;
sol = DSolve[eqn, {x[t], y[t]}, t]
```

and i need to plot 3 graphs x[t], y[t] and y[x]. 
I learned how to build the first two,

```
Plot[Evaluate[x[t] /. sol /. {C[1] -> 1, C[2] -> 1}], {t, 0, 10}]
Plot[Evaluate[y[t] /. sol /. {C[1] -> 1, C[2] -> 1}], {t, 0, 10}]
```

and i dont know how to build last y[x] and how to understand this. I add photo my task.
[image]

Comment: You meant to say  `y[t]` vs `x[t]`? if yes then `ParametricPlot[
 Evaluate[{x[t], y[t]} /. First[sol] /. {C[1] -> 1, C[2] -> 1}], {t, 
  0, 10}]`?

Comment: I hope this is what I need. thx

Answer (score 2):

This is more of a Mathematics question.

```
eqn = {x''[t] + w^2*x[t] == 0, y[t] == x'[t]}; w = 1;
sol = DSolve[eqn, {x[t], y[t]}, t];
xt = FullSimplify[x[t] /. sol /. {C[1] -> 1, C[2] -> 1}][[1]]
```

> $$x(t)=-\frac{\sin(t)}{2}$$

```
yt = FullSimplify[y[t] /. sol /. {C[1] -> 1, C[2] -> 1}][[1]]
```

> $$y(t)=-\frac{\cos(t)}{2}$$

Now, recalling the trignometric identity and using the appropriate forms of the above two solutions,

$$1=\cos^2(t)+\sin^2(t)=4y^2+4x^2,$$

which gives equation of circle $x^2+y^2=1/4$ with radius $1/2$. Thus, your $y=f(x)$ is

> $$y=\pm\sqrt{\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^2-x^2}$$.

```
Plot[{Sqrt[(1/2)^2 - x^2], -Sqrt[(1/2)^2 - x^2]}, {x, -0.5, 0.5}, AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

As I suggested in comment, the appropriate [command](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ParametricPlots.html) to use is `ParametricPlot`.

> In a parametric plot, you give both the $x$ and $y$ coordinates of each point as a function of a third parameter, say $t$.

Plotting (drawing) the circle with radius $1/2$ combine with parametric plot, we will see that both are the same,

```
Show[ParametricPlot[ {xt, yt}, {t, 0, 10}], ContourPlot[(x)^2 + (y)^2 == 1/4, {x, -5, 5}, 
                    {y, -3, 3}, ContourStyle -> {Red, Directive[Dashed]}]], Frame -> True]
```

[image]